# SonarQube: Unable to read and import the source file '.../somefile.js' with the charset : 'UTF-8'

Tags: .net, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to run SonarQube in Jenkins for my Visual Studio project. But it fails: "Unable to read and import the source file '.../_references.js' with the charset : 'UTF-8'".

I read that this might be because there is two or more _references.js files. I tried to exclude SonarQube from analyzing _references.js files but same error.

How could I fix this? Or is there some solution to really ignore SonarQube from analyzing _references.js files?

SonarQube version is 4.5.4

Comment: There is some [conversation](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Duplicate-file-names-td5012229.html) about sonar.supportSourceFileDuplications parameter. I have tried to add it as argument (/d:sonar.supportSourceFileDuplications=true) but seems that it ignores it.