# SonarQube - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read the source file - x.jpg with the charset : 'UTF-8'

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a project where SonarQube crashes during completion of the analysis for no reason (as far as I can see). We have many other projects which work fine with the same build steps.

The completion complains about:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read the source file : 'C:/TfsAgents/AgentB/_work/61/s/MyProject/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/docs/media/images/arrow.jpg' with the charset : 'UTF-8'.
at org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.scanner.IssueExclusionsLoader.execute(IssueExclusionsLoader.java:69)
```

I have tried excluding the whole `Content` folder and excluding all `*.jpg` files, and opening and resaving the jpg file to check it's ok (which it is).

I'm at a loss of what else to check to get this working except perhaps deleting the file.

Has anyone else seen this problem / got any possible causes? I can post more of the stack trace from SonarQube if it helps.

We're on SonarQube `Version 6.3 (build 19869)`

EDIT: This issue looks similar ([SonarQube: Unable to read and import the source file '.../somefile.js' with the charset : 'UTF-8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719244/sonarqube-unable-to-read-and-import-the-source-file-somefile-js-with-the)), but has no solution and the link in the comments doesn't shed much light on things either.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that your problem is caused by [SONAR-8995](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8995), which is addressed in 6.3.1 (out soon), and 6.4.

In brief, this is a bad interaction between issue exclusions and some updates to the way files are indexed for analysis in 6.3.